# Quaternion rotation does not work

Tags: c++, c, opengl, 3d, rotation

I want to make a quaternion based camera. In the internet I found this :
https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/a-simple-quaternion-based-camera-r1997

From which I took the code :

```
typedef struct { float w, x, y, z; } quaternion;

double length(quaternion quat)
{
  return sqrt(quat.x * quat.x + quat.y * quat.y +
              quat.z * quat.z + quat.w * quat.w);
}

quaternion normalize(quaternion quat)
{
  double L = length(quat);

  quat.x /= L;
  quat.y /= L;
  quat.z /= L;
  quat.w /= L;

  return quat;
}

quaternion conjugate(quaternion quat)
{
  quat.x = -quat.x;
  quat.y = -quat.y;
  quat.z = -quat.z;
  return quat;
}

quaternion mult(quaternion A, quaternion B)
{
  quaternion C;

  C.x = A.w*B.x + A.x*B.w + A.y*B.z - A.z*B.y;
  C.y = A.w*B.y - A.x*B.z + A.y*B.w + A.z*B.x;
  C.z = A.w*B.z + A.x*B.y - A.y*B.x + A.z*B.w;
  C.w = A.w*B.w - A.x*B.x - A.y*B.y - A.z*B.z;
  return C;
}

void RotateCamera(double Angle, double x, double y, double z)
{
  quaternion temp, quat_view, result;

  temp.x = x * sin(Angle/2);
  temp.y = y * sin(Angle/2);
  temp.z = z * sin(Angle/2);
  temp.w = cos(Angle/2);

  quat_view.x = View.x;
  quat_view.y = View.y;
  quat_view.z = View.z;
  quat_view.w = 0;

  result = mult(mult(temp, quat_view), conjugate(temp));
  View.x = result.x;
  View.y = result.y;
  View.z = result.z;
}
```

But Im having problems when trying to implement this line :

```
gluLookAt(Position.x, Position.y, Position.z,
      View.x, View.y, View.z, Up.x, Up.y, Up.z).
```

because I have no idea of what to use as 'Up', I tried with 0,0,0, but it only showed a black screen. Any help is greatly appreciated !

EDIT :

Somewhere on this site I found something like that that does convert a quaternion to a matrix. How can I use this matrix using `glMultMatrixf();`

```
float *quat_to_matrix(quaternion quat) {
    float matrix[16];
    double qx=quat.x;
    double qy=quat.y;
    double qz=quat.z;
    double qw=quat.w;
    const double n = 1.0f/sqrt(qx*qx+qy*qy+qz*qz+qw*qw);
    qx *= n;
    qy *= n;
    qz *= n;
    qw *= n;
    matrix={1.0f - 2.0f*qy*qy - 2.0f*qz*qz, 2.0f*qx*qy - 2.0f*qz*qw, 2.0f*qx*qz + 2.0f*qy*qw, 0.0f,
    2.0f*qx*qy + 2.0f*qz*qw, 1.0f - 2.0f*qx*qx - 2.0f*qz*qz, 2.0f*qy*qz - 2.0f*qx*qw, 0.0f,
    2.0f*qx*qz - 2.0f*qy*qw, 2.0f*qy*qz + 2.0f*qx*qw, 1.0f - 2.0f*qx*qx - 2.0f*qy*qy, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    return matrix;
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I used `glMultMatrixf()` and it worked. But I finally found out, that the output of `RotateCamera()` makes my Quaternion zero ? **Does anybody know whats wrong with this method :**

```
void RotateCamera(double Angle, double x, double y, double z)
{
  quaternion temp, quat_view, result;

  temp.x = x * sin(Angle/2);
  temp.y = y * sin(Angle/2);
  temp.z = z * sin(Angle/2);
  temp.w = cos(Angle/2);

  quat_view.x = View.x;
  quat_view.y = View.y;
  quat_view.z = View.z;
  quat_view.w = 0;

  result = mult(mult(temp, quat_view), conjugate(temp));
  View.x = result.x;
  View.y = result.y;
  View.z = result.z;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to me , but I will try to answer anyway :D ... why don't you just rotate it using glRotatef(angle,0,0,1) for rotation of the z axis , since the the definition of this function it is as follows : glRotatef(angle,x_axis,y_axis,z_axis) the last 3 parameters clamp to [0,1].

For the second question , from what I know you should decrement the angle, you can anyway experiment with the function to see for yourself ;) .

Comment: My problem is the https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6jdPPhIHSAhUG1xQKHdE_C_kQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGimbal_Lock&usg=AFQjCNF_DvCfBDs0Xc3vPw3h3CpPC74EJw&bvm=bv.146496531,d.d24 Gimbal Lock. I asked a similar question on maths site : Is there a easy way to overcome Gimbal Lock instead of quaternion rotation ?

Comment: i don't think so since I'm quite stuck at this same problem that you have... From my earlier earned experience i too find it hard to implement quaternions in camera rotation and movement * .
I tried using a View matrice which then suffers a translation then 2 rotations (y axis then x axis) which in a way worked but you are stuck in a fixed y position which means you cannot go down or up using camera view :) ...

Comment: oh and i did not mention ... the other way is to use euler angles which shoud suffice for experimentation .
You should check out this link : https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera
This is where I learned how to implement my first camera system ... credits go to the author of that site ofc :) ... i think that will surely help you :D

Comment: Yes, but I havent `glm`

Comment: i can tell  glm is pretty useful if you want to learn graphics . It helps a lot :) .
You can get it here : http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html

Comment: But Id like to have it compatible with almost every computer, even if they havent glm

Comment: The link i provided you with explains how the Lookat function computes the view matrice in steps and if you get glm you can also look into the source code to see how is the Lookat function is written exactly.You need to make use of the normalize , dot product and cross product functions which i guess you already have.

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look at it. I think it makes my problem a  bit clearer. I thought of using something else than quaternions but I can tink of nothing that does so.

Comment: with quaternions you could experiment with them like this : make a View matrice with -> lookAt(0.0f,0.0f,3.0f,0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f) for example  than multiply to it a translate matrice and 2 rotation matrices ,though you need to transform a quat into a matrice . This worked for me in some way but this one is also bugging me ... I am still using Euler angles atm.

Comment: id still like to use Euler Angles, but how can I rotate around a vector ?

Comment: using 2 angles yaw (for the x mouse axis) and pitch(for the y axis of the mouse)you declare a vec3 which will replace your view / front view vector in the look at function (or 4rd,5rd,6rd parameters) like this: vec3 front; front.x = cos(yaw)*cos(pitch); front.y = sin(pitch); front.z = sin(yaw)*cos(pitch); Normalize(front); then you call : lookAt(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,front.x,front.y,front.z,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

Comment: Thanks, thats useful to me.

Comment: But wont Gimbal Lock occur then ? My question is : How to rotate around the objects alignment ?

Comment: yes it will  unfortunately :/.Rotating your camera around an object  = change its position . For example for a rotation on the XZ axis you do LookAt(sin(angle)*radius,0.0f,cos(angle)*radius,front.x,front.y,front.z,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f‌​) .

Comment: Thanks, that helps me to understand LookAt. But one more question : I found a function to convert a quaternion to a matrix. Would it be easier to use this rotation matrix and multiply it by glMultMatrixf() ?

Comment: in my opinion, you should stick to the rough math , meaning you should use the quat to matrix conversion function...or eventually create it yourself if you can do and understand the math behind it.

Comment: Please have a look at my new edit, probably you have an idea about how to use the matrix...

Comment: Please also at my second edit. Im very close to it, but the RotateCamera makes my Quaternion always zero...

Comment: So you figured how to use the multmatrixf function ?Where is the View vector declared ?

Comment: The View vector is declared just in the code before the draw function. I can change it if I do the following : `View.x+=0.1f`, for example.

Comment: check the results by debugging your program(try rotating only one axis using x = 1.0f,y=0.0f,z=0.0f) and you also gotta make sure you have the quat math set up right .

Comment: Thanks, Ill check it out.

Comment: Id like to edit this question to a java question, I threw away my c code, and now Im having no problems(in java). Would it be ok for you if Id edit this question so that it handle an absolutely different topic because I have reached my question limit ?